# Is there a good way to apply pychecker/pylint to the python code in Tornado templates?

Tags: python, tornado, pylint, pychecker

I am using Tornado 2.0 (Python 2.6.5) to build a simple web app.

Naturally, my Tornado templates contain snippets of Python code. For my non-template code, I am using pychecker and pylint to check for errors, etc.

However, obviously pychecker and pylint can't be run over the templates directly, b/c the templates are not python files proper (for non-Tornado users: they are html-like snippets w/ some control sequences and embedded python code).

So, my question is: **can anyone suggest a good way to apply pychecker/pylint to the python code in these template files?** Presumably this would involve extracting the code from the files.

I can hazard a few guesses as to how to do this, but I am curious if other people perceive this as a problem and what solutions they have pursued. I am still fairly new to web app design/construction so I am interested in answers guided by practical experience.

Comment: There is no way. I recommend using view classes. Create a class per template, put all code to this class, then give instance of this class as a paramter to the template. As you can see you'll sooner or later end up problems with embedded Python code. It is very good practice of keeping all of your code in .py files for debugging and performance analysis reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mikko. I think your suggestion is definitely the way to go. Feel free to "upgrade" your comment to a full answer, so that I can give you more credit for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use view class pattern to avoid cluttering your template with Python code which cannot be analyzed.

- Create a Python class to process your view, instead of function
- Have all "template logic" code as class methods. Your template calls them like {{ view.get_full_name }} and def get_full_name(self): return self.item.first_name + " "  + self.item.last_name
- Make instance out of your class
- make **call**() as starting point for your processing
- Pass "self" to your template as a context var

Some instructions for Django, but generally all Python frameworks (Pyramid, Zope) follow the same pattern:

[Class views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742/class-views-in-django)

"$yourframeworkname view class" should yield more tutorials in Google.