# Import code inside a view. Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have simple code that I would like to import in each of my views:

```
           form = DocumentForm()
           user= request.user
           test1 = request.session.get('test1')
           ....
           context += {'form': form, 'test1':test1 ...}
```

I would like to know if there is a simple way to do this. I saw the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/

But I'm not sure to get how it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Personnaly, I create a model's method or create a file named `myapp/defs.py` where I write my methods.

Answer (score 0):

this would be one of the simplest ways:

```
def run_this_in_every_view(request) :
    form = DocumentForm()
    user= request.user
    test1 = request.session.get('test1')
    ....
    return {'form': form, 'test1':test1 ...}

def my_view(request) :
    context = {}

    ...

    context += run_this_in_every_view(request)
    return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

class based views would be the better way probably. this question has a good answer for that: [Class views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742/class-views-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) is for.